# Laravel 5.5 - Custom Validator for RegisterController

Tags: laravel

I want to define some custom rules for validate registration in a laravel 5.5 project.

Inside my AppServiceProvider.php i have set:

```
use Validator;
[...]    
     public function boot()
     {
         Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

         Validator::extend('checkPI', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
             // only for test
             return false;
         });
     }
```

This is my edited RegisterController.php

```
 $return = Validator::make($data, [
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        'partitaIva' => 'required|string|min:11|checkPI',
    ]);
```

Now if i try to launch registration i obtain:

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::extend()

in Validator::extend of AppServiceProvider. Where i'm wrong? How can i resolve?

Thank you!

Comment: Laravel 5.5 have changed method to use rule. Follow this guide to understand the new approach: http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-55-custom-validation-rules-exampleexample.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope this resolve your problem. Change the `use Validator;` to `use \Validator;`